# Recycler view not updating properly

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, kotlin

*I have asked this similar questions multiple times and its been more than 2 weeks that I am trying to figure out a solution for it. Yes, I am aware that there are multiple similar question but the reason why I am asking is because none of the solutions from stack over flow work.I am a **beginner** in Android development, hence I ask you to kindly help me with this problem. I have almost given up on my project.*

**How app works**

App has two activities. Main activity is used for showing data in form of card views using recycler view which is loaded from **SQ Lite DB**. User can click on a card which on clicking will launch a new activity(REFERENCE ACTIVITY). Data of clicked card is loaded in second activity. Here user can perform **UPDATE** or **DELETE** function.

**PROBLEM**

The problem is that I have to restart my app just to see a change in a note. For example, if I create a note in second activity and return to main activity, that **CREATED** note is **NOT** visible until app is restarted. Same goes for when a note is updated or deleted. Change only occurs when app is restarted.

**What I have tried so far...**

- called notifyDataSetChanged() in onRestart() of MAIN activity.
- Recalled whole load that loads recycler view items in first place in onRestart()
- Tried updating adapter with the new data

**----- CODES -----**

**MAIN ACTIVITY**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

var dbHandler: PediaDatabase = PediaDatabase(this)
var adapter: PediaAdapter? = null
var newAdapter: PediaAdapter? = null
var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager? = null
var list: ArrayList<UserNotes>? = ArrayList()
var listItems: ArrayList<UserNotes>? = ArrayList()
var updatedList: ArrayList<UserNotes> = ArrayList()
var tempList: ArrayList<UserNotes>? = null
var myPrefs: SharedPreferences? = null
var first_run: Boolean = true
var isCreated: Boolean = false
var isUpdated: Boolean = false
var isDeleted: Boolean = false
var isReturning: Boolean = false

var updatedTitle: String? = null
var updatedText: String? = null

val PREFS_NAME: String = "MYPREFS"
val REQUEST_CODE: Int = 1


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

     showOneTimeMessage()
     invalidateOptionsMenu()

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    {
        window.navigationBarColor = Color.BLACK
    }

}

override fun onRestart() {
    super.onRestart()

    if(isUpdated)
    {
        recyclerViewID.recycledViewPool.clear()
        var test = listItems!![adapPos]
        test.noteTitle = updatedTitle
        test.noteText = updatedText
        listItems!!.set(adapPos, test)
        adapter!!.notifyItemChanged(adapPos)

        isUpdated = false
    }
}


override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()

    if(isReturning)
    {
        adapter!!.updateResults(this.listItems!!)
        adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    adapter = PediaAdapter(this, listItems!!)
    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

    recyclerViewID.adapter = adapter
    recyclerViewID.layoutManager = layoutManager


    list = dbHandler.readAllNotes()

    for(reader in list!!.iterator())
    {
        var note = UserNotes()

        note.noteTitle = reader.noteTitle
        note.noteText = reader.noteText
        note.noteID = reader.noteID
        note.noteDate = reader.noteDate

        listItems!!.add(note)
    }

    adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()


    if(dbHandler.totalNotes() == 0) {
        recyclerViewID.visibility = View.GONE
    }
    else{
        recyclerViewID.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        showWhenEmptyID.visibility = View.GONE
    }
    recyclerViewID.hasFixedSize()
}





override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE)
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {
            //isCreated = data!!.extras!!.getBoolean("isCreated")

            updatedTitle = data!!.extras.getString("updatedTitle")
            updatedText = data!!.extras.getString("updatedText")

            isReturning = data.extras!!.getBoolean("returningBack")
           // isUpdated = data.extras!!.getBoolean("isUpdated")
        }
}


override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.top_menu, menu)

    val item = menu!!.findItem(R.id.delete_note_menu)
    item.setVisible(false)
    return true
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {

    if(item!!.itemId == R.id.add_note_menu){

        isNewNote = true
        startActivity(Intent(this, ReferenceActivity::class.java))
    }

    if(item!!.itemId == R.id.delete_note_menu)
    {

        Toast.makeText(this,"DELETED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}

private fun showOneTimeMessage()
{
    var data: SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0)
    if(data.contains("isShown"))
    {
        first_run = data.getBoolean("isShown", true)
    }


    Log.d("FIRST_RUN", first_run.toString())

    if(first_run)
    {
        val oneTimeMsg = SweetAlertDialog(this)
        oneTimeMsg.setTitleText("Hey there!")
        oneTimeMsg.setContentText("Thank you for downloading! Please don`t forget to rate our app :)").show()

        oneTimeMsg.setConfirmClickListener(object : SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener
        {

            override fun onClick(sweetAlertDialog: SweetAlertDialog?)
            {
                oneTimeMsg.dismissWithAnimation()
            }
        }).show()


        myPrefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0)
        var editor: SharedPreferences.Editor = (myPrefs as SharedPreferences).edit()
        editor.putBoolean("isShown", false)
        editor.commit()

    }
}
```

**REFERENCE ACTIVITY**

```
class ReferenceActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

var dbHandler: PediaDatabase? = null
var note = UserNotes()

var noteExisted: Boolean = false
var cardAdapterPos: Int? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reference)

    getSupportActionBar()!!.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM)
     getSupportActionBar()!!.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_toolbar)
      val dateTxtView = findViewById<View>(resources.getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", packageName)) as TextView


    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out)

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        window.navigationBarColor = Color.BLACK


    dbHandler = PediaDatabase(this)
    val data = intent
        if(isNewNote != true/*isNewNote.extras.getBoolean("isNewNote") != true*/)
        {
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN)

            if(data != null)
            {
                noteExisted = true

                this.cardAdapterPos = data.extras.getInt("cardPosition")
                cardID = data.extras.getInt("cardID")


                existingNote = dbHandler!!.readNote(cardID)

                refTitleID.setText(existingNote.noteTitle, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
                refTextID.setText(existingNote.noteText, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
                dateTxtView.text = existingNote.noteDate.toString()
            }
        }else{
            dateTxtView.text = "New note"
        }
}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()


    var title: String = refTitleID.text.toString().trim()
    var text: String = refTextID.text.toString().trim()

    if(existingNote.noteText == text && existingNote.noteTitle == title)
        finish()

    if(noteExisted)
    {
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(title))
            title = "No title"


        existingNote.noteTitle = title
        existingNote.noteText = text
        existingNote.noteDate = System.currentTimeMillis().toString() //TODO TRY THIS


        dbHandler!!.updateNote(existingNote)

        var dataCreate = this.intent
        dataCreate.putExtra("isUpdated", true)
        dataCreate.putExtra("updatedTitle", title)
        dataCreate.putExtra("updatedText",text)
        dataCreate.putExtra("returningBack", true)
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, dataCreate)


        finish()
    }
    else
    {
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(title) && TextUtils.isEmpty(text))
        {
            finish()
        }
        else
        {
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(title))
                title = "No title"

            note.noteTitle = title
            note.noteText = text
            note.noteDate = System.currentTimeMillis().toString()
           // note.noteID =

            dbHandler!!.createNote(note)

            var dataCreate = this.intent
            dataCreate.putExtra("isCreated", true)
            dataCreate.putExtra("returningBack", true)
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, dataCreate)

            finish()
        }
    }
}


override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {

    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.top_menu, menu)
    val addItem: MenuItem = menu!!.findItem(R.id.add_note_menu)
    val delItem:MenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.delete_note_menu)


    addItem.setVisible(false)
    delItem.setVisible(false)

    if(noteExisted)
        delItem.setVisible(true)

    return true
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {

    if(item!!.itemId == R.id.delete_note_menu)
    {
        val dialogMsg = SweetAlertDialog(this, SweetAlertDialog.WARNING_TYPE)
        dialogMsg.setTitleText("Are you sure?")
        dialogMsg.setContentText("You won`t be able to recover this note!")
        dialogMsg.setConfirmText("Yes, delete it!")

        dialogMsg.setConfirmClickListener(object: SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener {

            override fun onClick(sweetAlertDialog: SweetAlertDialog?) {
                dialogMsg.dismissWithAnimation()


                dbHandler!!.deleteNote(cardID)


                val successMsg = SweetAlertDialog(sweetAlertDialog!!.context, SweetAlertDialog.SUCCESS_TYPE)
                successMsg.setTitleText("Note deleted!")
                successMsg.setContentText("So long,note").show()
                successMsg.setCancelable(false)

                //TODO Disable 'OK' button on successMsg dialogbox

                Handler().postDelayed({
                    successMsg.dismissWithAnimation()
                    finish()
                }, 1200)

            }
        }).show()

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

**ADAPTER**

```
class PediaAdapter(private val context: Context,
               private var noteslist: ArrayList<UserNotes>): RecyclerView.Adapter<PediaAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): ViewHolder
{
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_row,p0,false)

    return ViewHolder(view, noteslist)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int
{
    return noteslist.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: ViewHolder, p1: Int)
{
    p0.bindItems(noteslist[p1])
}

inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View, list: ArrayList<UserNotes>): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener
{
    private var noteTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.listTitleID) as TextView
    private var noteText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.listTextID) as TextView

    var mList = list


    init
    {
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    fun bindItems(note: UserNotes)
    {
        //var id = note.noteID
        noteTitle.text = note.noteTitle
        noteText.text = note.noteText
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?)
    {

        var mPosition: Int =  adapterPosition //For forwarding position to ref activity
        var note = mList[mPosition]
        adapPos = adapterPosition


        var cardID = Intent(itemView.context, ReferenceActivity::class.java)
        cardID.putExtra("cardPosition", mPosition)
        cardID.putExtra("cardID", note.noteID) //TODO THIS IS FETCHING NOTE_ID VALUES FROM DB

        Toast.makeText(itemView.context, "card id = " + note.noteID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        itemView.context.startActivity(cardID)
    }

}

fun updateResults(items: ArrayList<UserNotes>)
{
    this.noteslist = items
}
```

**Yes,** I know its hard to go through someones code. I have tried to fix it many times sitting all day trying to figure it out and still no luck. I am requesting you to please help me with this. I don't care if you do in Java, I just need a way to fix it.

Comment: You override `onActivityResult()` in MainActivity but this will only be called if you used `startActivityForResult()` in the first place. I can't find any line with `startActivityForResult()` so maybe this is one reason  why your code doesn't work as intended

Comment: @0X0nosugar   Problem is that, even if I change the logic of code, say, I call notifyDataSetChanged() in onRestart(), nothing happens. Why? Even when using 'bad' solutions still nothing works.

Comment: I would try to find out what's wrong by copying your code and running it on my own machine but unfortunately there are some classes missing, so that's not an option. The logic in onStart() and onRestart() *does* look a bit tangled (for instance, if isReturning == true, you do something with the old Adapter but a few lines later you discard it entirely and only use a new Adapter instance), so I'd really like to use my debugger to find out what's going on

Comment: @0X0nosugar Alright, I am sharing my project files with you. You can download it and run it on your machine. Here is the link to google drive: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hsRLOJYYnBX7OlvLc7eY6VYYBBSYSpNZ

Comment: Looks like sharing your code was a good idea - @sandip was finally able to help you. But please keep your question like it was or even add the missing parts - future readers may not be able to find your code on google drive any more and we always try to have questions-and-answers not only for the OP but also for all those who may find themselves in a similar situation in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your MainActivity in `AndroidManifest.xml` file like this.

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

Before Finishing 'ReferenceActivity' (i.e calling finish()), make an Intent call to your 'MainActivity'. Also, override 'onNewIntent()' method inside your 'MainActivity'.

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
```

Inside 'onNewIntent()' method, load you data again as you're already doing in 'onStart()' and 'onRestart()'.

Explanation, What we're doing is adding a single reference of our 'MainActivity' in Activity Stack, so whenever an intent call is made to 'MainActivity' instead of creating multiple reference it just create one reference and call newIntentMethod every time.

Hopefully, that will fix your issue.

Comment: I have tried calling startActivity(intent) on reference activity after I am done creating/updating or deleting a note. It just keeps stacking up main activity which is bad thing.

Comment: Are you declare `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

Comment: I have tried it, main activity is still stacking up. On top of that, when main activity is called again, adapter losses reference to card view data, hence when I click on newly created note or existing note, it just opens "new note" tab. Data is loaded. I have provided source code of my project up. Could you please check it?

Comment: Hey! I just almost fixed it with your help! Now there is a problem, for example when I create a new note, go back to main activity and see that newly created note. But when I click on it, app thinks that I am creating a new note and does not loads corresponding data. How to fix it?

Comment: hey, I just figured it that the solution creates another problem. When app is paused and relaunched by clicking on launcher icon again, app is restarted. How to fix it?

Comment: I am sorry I would not like to share my app`s code publicly anymore due to security reasons. The reason why app is behaving is like that is because of launchMode="singleTask". If I remove it, problem is fixed.

Comment: Needless to say, launchMode did fix the problem but also introduced another problem for my app. However, your solution provided an answer to what I asked in the original post. It was my fault that I copied the wrong code and pasted it any my own 'answer'. What I meant was that just call notifyDataSetChanged() in onStart. I am not sure why all of a sudden notfiydatasetchanged() started working because before it did not.